# Java: Enemy follow Player

Tags: java

I have an enemy and a player. What I am trying to do is have my enemy continuously follow my player while he moves. I have code that does that, but the speed of the goblin is different depending on where my character is relative to the enemy: such as when I'm up and to the left of the enemy (negative of the enemy), it moves super fast and is in my player. However, when I'm down and to the right (positive of the enemy) every thing is fine. Any ideas?

Here is what I have in my enemy update function:

```
        MoveToX = Board.playerOne.getX();
        MoveToY = Board.playerOne.getY();

        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(MoveToX - x, 2) + Math.pow(MoveToY - y, 2));

        amountToMoveX = (((MoveToX - x) / distance) * speed);
        amountToMoveY = (((MoveToY - y) / distance) * speed);

        x+= amountToMoveX;
        y += amountToMoveY;
```

EDIT:

```
        //x is the enemies (this x) and the same for y


        int MoveToX = Board.playerOne.getX();
        int MoveToY = Board.playerOne.getY();

        int diffX = MoveToX - x;
        int diffY = MoveToY - y;

        float angle = (float)Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);

        x += speed * Math.cos(angle);
        y += speed * Math.sin(angle);
```

My new algorithm is this. However I am getting the same issue which is that my enemy moves as fast as me while its negative to the player.

Comment: You have these nice convenient `amountToMoveX` and `amountToMoveY` variables.  maybe you can fire up your debugger, and see what their values are.  You should also check the values of your other related variables.  Odds are that one of them isn't what you expect it to be

Comment: I think it is something related to type casting. Try to use double instead of float and have two variables: deltaX and deltaY instead of (MoveToX - x) and (MoveToY - y).

Comment: please report the types of all the variables you used.

Comment: Fyi, you can shorten `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(MoveToX - x, 2) + Math.pow(MoveToY - y, 2));` to `Math.hypot(MoveToX - x, MoveToY - y)`, although this won't change/fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
int diffX = moveToX - x;
int diffY = moveToY - y;

float angle = (float)Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);

x += speed * Math.cos(angle);
y += speed * Math.sin(angle);
```

`diffX` and `diffY` are the components of the vector from the enemy to the player. With that, you can calculate the angle by taking the arctangent of the components of the vector. `Math.cos(angle)` is the normalized `x` component of the distance vector `<diffX, diffY>`-> (`cos^2(x) + sin^2(x) = 1`), and multiplying that by `speed` gives you the velocity at which the enemy moves in the `x` direction. The same rules apply for `y` and `Math.sin(angle)`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested above, But I am still getting that issue I explained above: When I am negative to the enemy it moves as fast as the player.

Comment: What are the units of moveToX, x, moveToY, and y? Are they supposed to be `int`s?

Comment: As far as I know I don't think they have to be ints. they just have to be readable by the graphics. Yes, they are ints, but I can change them to floats.

Comment: I changed them to floats, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: I would debug the program to see exactly what is going on. This code works if implemented correctly. I use the exact same technique for another game of mine. If `x^2+y^2` is not equal to `speed` squared, then you have a problem.